# glyphicon in an xml label, is that possible?

Tags: xml, glyphicons

I'm working on a Joomla template, and would like to use glypicons or font awesome in my templateDetails.xml file. So far, I can't get it done.

I don't know much about xml, this is what I came up with, but I get a parsing error:

```
label="&lt;span class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-envelope&quot;&gt;"A label" &lt;/span&gt;">
```

Answer (score 1):

First, please don't tell us you get an error without telling us what the error is. You could have saved me at least 10 seconds working out what's wrong.

What's wrong is that you've got an an XML attribute `label="...."` and the value of the label contains unescaped quotation marks. You've carefully escaped some of the quotes as `&quot;` and you've failed to escape others.